# Setting value on one dataframe based on the id and value from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, bigdata

I've got problem with my dataframes.

First dataframe looks like:

```
id     0    1    2    3

100    0    0    0    0
101    0    0    0    0
102    0    0    0    0
103    0    0    0    0
```

Second dataframe looks like:

```
id     num

100    1
100    2
100    3
101    0
101    3
102    1
103    2
103    3
```

And I want to change in the first dataframe zeros to ones in the specific rows represented by "id" in the columns which are presented in the second dataframe in column "num" with specific "id". So in the end I would like to have first dataframe changed to:

```
id     0    1    2    3

100    0    1    1    1
101    1    0    0    1
102    0    1    0    0
103    0    0    1    1
```

How can I do that? I know that I can use for loop (which I've already prepared), but my dataframes are very big and it will take about 4 hours to finish. I was thinking about mapping in pandas, but I didn't have a solution.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming the first data frame `df1` and second one `df2`, you can pivot the data frame `df2`:

```
df2['value'] = 1
df1 = df2.pivot_table(index='id', columns='num', values='value', fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
num  0  1  2  3
id             
100  0  1  1  1
101  1  0  0  1
102  0  1  0  0
103  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: This solution worked for me having 32GB RAM. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `max` by index for indicator values, if need count values use `sum` instead `max`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df2.set_index('id')['num']).max(level=0)
print (df)
     0  1  2  3
id             
100  0  1  1  1
101  1  0  0  1
102  0  1  0  0
103  0  0  1  1
```

If possible more rows or columns in first DataFrame add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('id')['num']).max(level=0)
        .reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.columns, fill_value=0))
```

Comment: `Unable to allocate 43.1 GiB for an array with shape (1761, 3287080) and data type int64` second number is the lenght of the second dataframe. First dataframe is about 400k lenght. Do I need more RAM?

Comment: @maliniaki - I think yes, unfortunately :(